# how do we make a program output a int?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code that has a while loop and inside are executions that show how many sentences have executed. To show you what I mean, here is my code:

```
while riddle < 11:
    print('this is the '+riddle+ 'th execution')
    riddle = riddle+1
```

my problem is, if i run it, i have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thejackl/hello world/hello_world.py", line 62, in <module>

   print('this is the '+riddle+ 'th execution')

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

More information:

- i am using python 2
- my complier is pycharm

Comment: `+riddle+` -> `+str(riddle)+`

Comment: um what did you mean?

Comment: Make that change in your code

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: `+` can add two `int`s, or two `str`s. It cannot add a `str` and an `int`; you need to convert the `int` explicitly first.

Comment: anyway can you convert it into an answer please so I can accept it first?